# mysql multiple joins query not returning desired ouput

Tags: mysql, join

I have three tables `customers`, `orders`, `payments`

I am trying to get the record with inner join  of a customer with his different orders and payment methods he use against the orders.

For example

```
customer_name  Order_status  Payment_method 
David          shipped       CASH
David          cancelled     CHEQUE
```

When I run the query it repeats the record three times and result also not as I mention above in example.

Here is query.

```
 SELECT cust_name
      , order_status
      , pay_method 
   FROM customer 
  INNER JOIN order_tbl ON customer.cust_id = order_tbl.cust_id 
  INNER JOIN payments ON payments.cust_id = order_tbl.cust_id
```

Is my query alright or do I need to mention my db structure as well?

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: i have provided already desired result at the top in the example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a relationship there. Your `orders` and `payments` need to link together somehow, i'm assuming there should be an `order_id` column in both tables ?

```
SELECT cust_name
    , order_status
    , pay_method 
FROM    customer 
        INNER JOIN order_tbl 
            ON customer.cust_id = order_tbl.cust_id 
        INNER JOIN payments 
            ON  payments.cust_id = order_tbl.cust_id 
            AND payments.order_id = orders_tbl.order_id --<<--- this line here is missing
```

If you dont have that kind of link, how do you logically link a payment to an order - because that will be your link that you're missing.

Comment: please can you tell how can i make my self strong in relationships, is there any website which teach specifically sql relationships

Answer (score 0):

You are getting duplicate records because the criteria is matched, nothing wrong with MySQL, it's returning results based on what you asked. Have you checked the ID's of the duplicate records to make sure that they are different? It may be the same record with different payment ID, so it will definitely return the customer and order records that are related for each record that a relationship exists. You could use `DISTINCT(THE_FIELD)` if you want to make the query distinct based on some criteria.

I am answering with limited knowledge on your project based on the information you provided. As mentioned in the comment above, more information would get an even better answer.

Comment: DB STRUCTURE:   Customer table: cust_id, cust_name, cust_city.   Order table: order_id, order_status, cust_id.   Paymens table: pay_id, cust_id, pay_method, amount, order_id

Answer (score 0):

You must probably missed using the primary key of order_tbl to join the third table.